# Binary classification (logistic regression) predict wrong label with high accuracy

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, predict

I have a problem that a binary Logistic regression (using scikit-learn python=2.7) classification that is predicting the wrong/opposite class with a high accuracy. That is, after fitting the model the predicted score and predicted probabilities for each class are very consistent but always of the wrong class. I cannot share the data, but some pseudo-code of my approach is:

```
X = np.vstack((cond_1, cond_2))  # shape of X = 200*51102
y = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(cond_1)), np.ones(len(cond_2)])

scls = []
clfs = []
scores = []

for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    clf = LogisticRegression(C=1)
    scl = StandardScaler()
    scl.fit(X[train])
    X_train = scl.transform(X[train])
    scls.append(scl)
    X_test = scl.transform(X[test])
    clf.fit(X_train, y[train])
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    scores.append(roc_auc_score(y[test], y_pred))
```

The roc_auc scores have a mean of 0.065% and a standard deviation of 0.05% so there seems to be going something, but what? I have plotted the features and they seem to be okay normally distributed. I also look that at the probabilities from predict_proba and they are mostly above 80% for the wrong class/label.

Any ideas what is going on and/or how to proper diagnose the problem?

I apologise for not being able to ask a more precise question but I'm lacking the vocabulary.

Comment: print the confusion matrix. Is the data highly unbalanced? E.g. too many entries in the training data which are close to each other and very few outliers? Maybe the data is not very linear.